# Single `c_cpp_properties.json` for multiple folders?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In a VS Code workspace I have several folders included.

```
{
    "folders": 
    [
        {
            "path": "C:\\folder1"
        },
        {
            "path": "C:\\folder2"
        },
        {
            "path": "C:\\folder3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to use one single `c_cpp_properties.json` file (to define include paths and other settings) for all 3 folders? I would like to avoid having a `c_cpp_properties.json` file in each folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generaly this seems not to be possible.
The only way is to have all directories share the same root direcory, and then to place a   `.vscode` directory inside this root:

```
c:/root_dir/ 
c:/root_dir/folder1
c:/root_dir/folder2
c:/root_dir/folder3
c:/root_dir/.vscode
c:/root_dir/.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json
```